# Windows Batch & VLC Issues

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file, vlc-media-player, audio-conversion

Currently I am attempting to write a batch file that recursively converts all .wav files in my folder into .ogg files and places them into a folder on a different disk using vlc's command line commands. So far, the script works as intended, except for one small issue, vlc://quit is not working, period.

```
@Echo Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /s "C:\Users\*\Music\Ultimate Game Music Collection\*.wav"') DO (

set file1=%%~nf.ogg
echo "file :" !file1!
set fic1=%%f
echo "file :" !fic1!
set destination=F:\myMusic\ogg\!file1!
echo "Destination :" "!destination!"


CALL "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --ignore-config -I dummy --dummy-quiet -vv "!fic1!" --sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=ogg,dst="!destination!"}" vlc://quit

)

echo .
echo conversion finished
pause
```

What is occurring is this;

I run the batch file, it posts only what is set as 'echo' (i.e. -vv is showing nothing), .wav is converted into a .ogg and placed into the new destination, vlc stops, no more files are converted.

At this point, if I go into Task Manager and end vlc.exe's process, it will then move on to the next file, but with over 5000 files to convert...I made this to be a start & forget.

I have searched all over trying to find an answer to this to no avail. I have tried the --ignore-config, which did not work. I even tried adding a separate taskkill command after the call, which also did not work ( even with /t and /f). Any help or insight you all can provide as to why vlc://quit is not working, or how to fix it, will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is your double quotes (the last one) off @ ,dst="!destination!"}"? Is it an extra one or should you have added one earlier?

Comment: `vlc://quit` may cause funny behavior in batch files. Try using instead the option of `vlc --play-and-exit `.

Comment: @harrymc , your suggestion worked. If you add it as an answer, I will select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vlc://quit` is unreliable in the batch environment and may cause funny behavior in
that environment.

Use instead the option of :

```
vlc --play-and-exit
```